# Can't install OS or boot into live USB

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, usb

I don't know what the problem is exactly. The other day I turned my PC on running linux lite and the resolution was all wrong on one of my monitors. So I rebooted it through a button I have on my panel, but it wouldn't boot, just showed a flashing white cursor in the top left corner.

I made a bootable usb and booted into it, but my monitor says that it's the wrong resolution and can't display it. So I went to a tty terminal (which worked) and copied all my files to a USB stick, so all my files are fine.

I tried installing bunsenlab just for a change, but that got stuck at "checking network hardware" (or something similar).

That got rid of my original os, so now there's no os installed, but I can't install another. I think it must be a problem with my HDD, and have tried formatting it, but I'm still stuck.

Is there a way to just completely wipe/reset the HDD to install a fresh os on it? I couldn't find anything online that did what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Edits:

I tried installing `linux-lite-6.2-64bit.iso` but that didn't work - just went black. The live had the same problem as stated above.

All the installation media was made from .iso files downloaded from the official sites and burnt to a usb stick using the build-in raspberry pi imager.

The image of bunsenlab I tried was `beryllium-1-amd64.hybrid.iso`

I'm booting by pressing F8 and selecting my usb from the menu of drives. Quick boot is disabled.

I have made a Linux Lite media and booted, but I can't get it to output in the correct resolution for my monitor. The tty terminals work fine, but when I go back to the graphics (idk what it's called) it says it's displaying an unsupported resolution no matter what monitor I use.

Also, legacy usb support is off. There is no other option to do with legacy in the boot section of BIOS. I managed to install LL months ago, it just stopped working yesterday.

I get these messages when shutting down live session from tty terminal

[image: errors]

I disconnected the HDD, and it boots into the live session without a problem. So it appears that the HDD is the problem.

Comment: You're somewhat confused and it reflects back to the question which is very confusing and the title doesn't match the body of text. [edit]ing is strongly recommended. Please add hardware specifications and the exact versions of the OSes you tried, how the installation/live media was made, how are you booting, etc. And, of course, you could boot before, something else happened that prevented the live session/installation but that isn't the same as "can't boot". Also check your hardware, namely the HDD if you suspect it. And no, there's no such thing as "wiping the drive from the BIOS"...

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks, I'll add them. I saw some stuff online about wiping the drive from BIOS, but I was probably misunderstanding it. I don't know how to check my HDD, and I don't have another to check if it's a problem with that one.

Comment: An ASUS P7H55-M motherboard is old but not that much that it can't cope with a modern mainstream distro like Ubuntu or derivatives. Linux Lite is a good choice, arguably better than BunsenLabs for newbies to get going and manage comfortably. Why don't you make a proper LL media, boot it and then use the tools (Disks, GParted, etc.) to check the drive? There's never a need to wipe it regardless of the method. If you want to start from a clean slate Gparted > Device menu > Create a new partition table, chose "GPT".

Comment: Also make sure you're booting in **UEFI mode**. Disable "legacy/CSM" in UEFI ("BIOS").

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have made a LL media and booted, but I can't get it to output in the correct resolution for my monitor. The tty terminals work fine, but when I go back to the graphics (idk what it's called) it says it's displaying an unsupported resolution no matter what monitor I use.

Comment: Also, legacy usb support is off. There is no other option to do with legacy in the boot section of BIOS. I managed to install LL months ago, it just stopped working yesterday.

Comment: So there's there's something wrong with the graphics. The HDD may or may not have issues - we can't know until it's tested - but certainly isn't the cause of the current problem with the live session.

Comment: Just because it's suggested you don't have to open a chat room. This isn't a forum. As said ion the first comment you should [e4dit] the question to add new or requested information, etc.

Comment: Okay, I've added more info to the question.

Comment: Thank you for editing. Now, the error messages strongly suggest a problem with the drive but, again, it shouldn't have any impact on the ability to run a normal live session. I suggest resetting UEFI ("BIOS") and go from there. You may also try disconnecting the HDD.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have booted without HDD and it works (also added it to question)

Comment: It's time to replace the drive then. A know good drive should work and allow a proper installation.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Okay, thank you for your help.